# Isometries of $\mathbb{R}^3$ by complex numbers.

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers

I know that the isometries of $\mathbb{R}^3$ which preserve orientation and which fix one point, say origin, can be represented by complex numbers; they are described by the well known Mobius transformations.

**Q.** If we consider the group of all isometries of $\mathbb{R}^3$ (preserving/ not preserving orientation), can we describe them by complex numbers?

Comment: inversion is not an isometry. so what are the isometric mobius transformations?

Comment: The Mobius transformations which represent isometries of sphere are of the form $z\mapsto \frac{az+b}{-\overline{b}z+\overline{a}}$. Such Mobius transformations form a group called $PSU(2,\mathbb{C})$, projective special unitary group, and it is isomorphic to $SO(3,\mathbb{R})$, the group of rotations of sphere.

Comment: thanks. i guess all the work is hidden in that isomorphism. i will have to go back check how it works.